# Is there any phpunit function to check whether particular element is present in html table?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I am looking for the way in phpunit to get the function which can check whether particular string is present in any of the cells of the html table.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's called assertRegExp(): http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertRegExp

Also assertContains() might help you: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertContains